# MVC _Layout header

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using _Layout for the header and footer to be included in all pages.

However, the strange thing is that the header is not responding on clicks on the index but everything is working well on all other pages.

Basically the header is made up of dropdown menu items and when I click a dropdown item the list of items show on all pages but not the index.

I don't think I have any code to post since the code is working but not on the index.

I included this on all .cshtml files

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NameOfPage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Has anyone ever encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. A stylesheet which was recently imported was affecting the layout file. Thanks